# Ethereum wallet is stuck at "looking for peers"

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm trying to create a private network or test network to work with smart contracts. But when I start ethereum wallet it is always getting stuck at "Looking for peers....". Below is the screenshot for the same.

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

I'm using ubuntu 16.04(64-bit) and Geth version is: 1.7.3-stable

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to work genesis file init

file name code use and file name: computer any dir file save `/genesis.json`

```
{
    "nonce"     : "0x0000000000000055",
    "mixHash"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "difficulty": "0x20000",
    "gasLimit"  : "0x800000",
    "timestamp" : "0x0",
    "extraData" : "",
    "coinbase"  : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "alloc"     : {},
    "config"    : {
        "chainId": 100,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    }
}
```

Then this commend run :

```
 geth --datadir "D:\CHAINDATAFINAL" init genesis.json
```

`D:\CHAINDATAFINAL` miens database directory and genesis file directory genesis file  directory,Example `E:\database\genesis.json`

Then private network create  this commend run geth directory:

```
geth --networkid 20 --port 60303 --rpc --lightkdf --cache 16 --datadir "D:\CHAINDATAFINAL" console
```

then private network create check this network commend:

```
$ admin
```

and

```
network id = 20;
```

> Important Note: After that mist/ethereum wallet open

If you have genesis file already init , then you do not need to genesis file init .Then you start from the private network commend run

try it then problem solve

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is poor engineering behind Mist wallet (and blockchain idea in general, of course), which would not run on HDD:

https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/3097

you can try using parity wallet, sometimes it works:

https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases